# Issue with Multisite wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, multisite

I have successfully installed multisite on wordpress version 4.3.1, and added some sites to the network. After adding the site to network, only the wp-admin is working, can't access the added site's home page. While accessing the site, I am getting white blank page. I checked the server logs, but couldn't find anything there.

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: place this code in config.php file and try to trace code : define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: once done let me know more about error description!!

Comment: @Anand Thanks. I did this and I got some errors related to one plugin named "qtrnasalate", I disabled that plugin, and those errors were gone. But After that we got errors related to theme we are using.